# how to display images with different height size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a row, and the row has 3 articles, every article has one photo inside it,
But the problem is when i go to display the row some problem occurs,
The problem is the photos can't be the same height size and this is making my website look bad. Image link ------- https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5EVB.png

note the every photo height is different from the other one

using bootstrap

my code

```
'<div class='row'>
         // product 1
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
   <div class="thumbnail">
     <img src="/*Path here*/">
     <div class="caption max">
       <h2>/*subject*/</h2>
       <h4>Selling by /*name*/</h2>
       <p>/*main-information*/</p>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
          // product 2
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
   <div class="thumbnail">
     <img src="/*Path here*/">
     <div class="caption max">
       <h2>/*subject*/</h2>
       <h4>Selling by /*name*/</h2>
       <p>/*main-information*/</p>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
         // Product 3
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
   <div class="thumbnail">
     <img src="/*Path here*/">
     <div class="caption max">
       <h2>/*subject*/</h2>
       <h4>Selling by /*name*/</h2>
       <p>/*main-information*/</p>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div> // closing row '
```

Thank you.

Comment: give the image width and height with css

Comment: set a height on the image tag directly or CSS

Comment: i did already but the images heights are different from each other

Comment: @Abdullrahman.Shebli show us what you exactly did, we can't judge by the pictures

Comment: So to be clear you want equal heights for all your images?

Comment: Yup and i wrote my code above

Comment: @Roljhon i wrote my code above , if you have any tips please help me thank you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css"> 
    /* thubnail div */
    .thumbnail {overflow: hidden; box-sizing: border-box;}
    /* all images in thumbnail div*/
    .thumbnail img{min-width: 200px; min-height: 123px; width: 200px; height: 123px; max-width: 200px; max-height: 123px; } 
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a same size for images:

```
.sameSize{
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
}
```

If you do not want this you can set same height for articles.

Answer (score 0):

Set min-height to whole container

Comment: Please try to expand on this answer. Like this it’s barely helpful for future readers.